# Head bone moves top portion of body back, but leaves the eye lid sticking out far from eye ball

Tags: mesh, rigging, vertex-weights

https://www.twitch.tv/videos/771914889

This video should explain everything hopefully, and it also shows a lot of whats going on with my problem.

Comment: so you don't want the eyelid to move up? in that case make sure that only the bone that is supposed to move it influence it, and not the other bones...

Comment: i would really suggest you to explain what is that is in the video so that people are not going to other platforms , and many of then might skip this because of you not giving full detail , so elaborate what you want as a text , small videos are Okay but this is too big

Comment: @moonboots but then it wouldn't move in unison with the mesh around it.  Also, having no other weights assigned to it from other bones would make it move without stretching, so blinking would no longer work.

Comment: if it's parented to a bone which is parented to the head bone, it will move along. For the stretching you can create a second bone to control the eyelid or a lattice?

Comment: @SHikhaMittal The video explains almost everything within the first 2-3 minutes, the rest was me going through the bone details again.  

I'll summarize my problem: 

I have a mushroom character with an Eye below the Mushrooms cap, this is the Eye I'm trying to rig up for eye tracking, but the Mushrooms cap is his head.  So when he leans backward the Eye below the cap tries to follow him, along with the Eye lid, and during a Blinking Animation it appears that the bottom of the Eye lid will be jetted out too far from the eye ball, meaning there is a gap between the eye lid and eye ball.

Comment: @moonboots I need something to be applied to the bottom of the eyelid when the character leans back to bring the bottom of the eyelid closer to the eye.

Comment: If I open the N panel in Edit mode, I can see that the eyelid is influenced by Head, Chest and Highhigheyebrow, while it should only be influenced by the latter, and maybe some other ones if necessary

Comment: @moonboots  that just won't work though, because when I rotate the headbone to look up or down in the game I want to export this model to, the eye brow needs to move with the skin around it, like... I can't have it moving out of place, so it needs to be weighted to the chest and head like all the skin around it is.

Comment: maybe try shapekeys, and shapekeys with drivers?

Answer (score 0):

"why not just use the bone to make a shape key for blinking then remove the bone after transfering it weight to the head"

this ended up working for me!

I made a shape key with the uppereyebrow bone (Highhigheyebrow) using the CAT5 (CATS?) plugin, then I renamed the Vertex Group for Highhigheyebrow to Head2, which applies it to the Head2 Bone, and this works!